# Joomla поменять состояние записи publish/unpublish

Tags: joomla

Пытаюсь разобраться в изменении состояния в своем компоненте, за основу взял `com_banners.banners`, кнопка `banners pinned` `onclick="return listItemTask('cb0','comments.publish')"`

В БД таблица с тестовыми записями

```
id  |  name   |   published
1   |  test   |   0
2   |  test   |   0
3   |  test   |   0
```

При клике  по кнопке изменяется состояние записи с *id = 1*, поробовал изменить *id* на случайный(взял 22). При клике по кнопке изменения состояния добавляется новая запись с пустыми полями кроме поля *published*, оно менятся взависимости от состояния. Где я что упустил?

***Joomla! 3.4.3***

Comment: Тема закрыта!) Сам разобрался

Comment: добавь решение к своему вопросу и получи награду "Самоучка"